# Creating a Total of subtotals

Tags: c#, textbox

Hi im trying to create this program where the txtbox1  will  multiply on user's input and automatically shows the total in decimal point same as in other txtboxes, but i'm having a trouble to sum up all the subtotals of every result to overall txtbox total

here is my code in every subtotals

```
private void txtbox11_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbox12.Text))
        txtTotal11.Text =
            (Convert.ToInt32(txtbox11.Text)*Convert.ToDecimal(112.61)).ToString();
}

private void txtbox12_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbox12.Text))
        txtTotal12.Text =
            (Convert.ToInt32(txtbox12.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(32.10)).ToString();
}
```

How do i automatically get the sum of txtTotal11 & txtTotal12 to display on txtTotal13?
or should i put an event like "textChanged" on every txtTotal# too?
thanks guys i'm really having a headache on this.

Comment: In your code, you are never accessing `txtTotal13`.

Comment: First, clean up the code. Separate the conversions from the math. Then update the textboxes you want in all relevant events which means, put the code in both events. Remove conversions of decimals like `32.10` to decimals. Change the empty check to IsNullOrWhitespace.

Comment: yes, you should add textChanged to all subtotals textBoxes and calculate sum off subtotals and assign value to grandTotal textbox

Comment: yeah i haven't put my code on txtbox13 because it wont work but if you need it here it is:


        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTotal13.Text))
            txtTotal13.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(txtTotal9.Text) + (Convert.ToDecimal(txtTotal10.Text) + (Convert.ToDecimal(txtTotal11.Text) + (Convert.ToDecimal(txtTotal12.Text))))))))))))))).ToString();
        
i am just a beginner on this language

Answer (score 1):

It will be something like:

```
private void txtboxSubTotal1_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CalcGrandTotal();
}

private void txtboxSubTotal2_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CalcGrandTotal();
}

private void CalcGrandTotal()
{
   decimal grandTotal = 0;
   decimal parseValue= 0;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtboxSubTotal1.Text) && decimal.TryParse(txtboxSubTotal1.Text, parseValue))
        grandTotal  += parseValue;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtboxSubTotal2.Text) && decimal.TryParse(txtboxSubTotal2.Text, parseValue))
        grandTotal  += parseValue;

txtboxGrandTotal.Text = grandTotal.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (in every TextChanged event)

```
decimal total13;
private void txtbox11_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbox12.Text))
        var thisTotal = (Convert.ToInt32(txtbox11.Text)*Convert.ToDecimal(112.61)).ToString();

        txtTotal11.Text = thisTotal

        total13 += thisTotal
        txtTotal13.Text = thisTotal.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Please mark one of the posts as an answer if it resolved resolved your question. Thanks.